# Android: What object best represents a drawing surface?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am working on a drawing application for Android, and one of my intents is to allow users to share their work with others. I want there to be a standardized size to the images, so my intent is to make a 'page' object that can be drawn on and which can be easily saved and exported. When the resolution of the page doesn't match the resolution of the screen of the device in use, the goal is to let zooming in or out handle it. The problem is I'm not sure what kind of object best represents this idea. I was going to just draw to canvas and save the drawings to a file, but as I learn more about Android, the canvas seems a less attractive option than I thought. I've been considering an image format, but I'm having difficulty finding what kind of things exist for this in Android. Could anyone help me out on this matter? I apologize if it comes off  as vague, I'm still new to android development.

Comment: Why does the canvas seem unappealing?  If you want to pass it around as an image then the canvas makes it very easy to do by creating a new canvas with a bitmap as the backing structure.  This is how I have done before with a pretty similar app.  **EDIT** There is an example of this in the API demos (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/android-sdk-4.4.2_r1.0.1/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.java)

Comment: It was my naivety that suggested it was unappealing. I didn't (and still don't) fully understand what the Canvas is and how it works. I appreciate the link, and will glean from it what I can.